# Update arrays while Iterating through a table

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying to update multiple arrays inside the table users.I think I'm supposed to use forEach for nested queries, but can't make it work. Below is what I tried:

```
r.db('mydb').table('users').forEach(
      function(user){
        return update({
          upvotelist: user('upvotelist').append(0),
          downvotelist: user('downvotelist').append(0)}
        )
      } 
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this with `update` by itself:

```
r.db('mydb').table('users').update(function(user) {
  return {
    upvotelist: user('upvotelist').append(0),
    downvotelist: user('downvotelist').append(0)};
})
```

`foreach` is for more complicate situations where you want to issue a write to a row based on another row.

Comment: Fast response. Thanks